# ACHEFT-Debit possible with webform_civicrm?

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, webform-civicrm, iats

Webform CiviCRM module can do credit card payments - but what about ACHEFT-Debit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is now possible! For both CAD and USD.

- Pull latest webform_civicrm module: 
  git clone https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm
- Pull latest iATS Payments extension: 
  git clone
  https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm

Example of USD Checkout:

[image]

Comment: I like how you failed to point out the implication that you need to use iATS Payments. But you do.